# How to add more grids in seaborn barplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

```
df.columns = ['feature','nunique']

sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(10,8)})
ax = sns.barplot(y='feature', x='nunique', data=df, orient = 'h')
```

[image]

How to divide nunique (x-axis) into smaller grids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ticker from matplotlib, so from the [vignette](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/ticker_api.html), it does:

> class matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(base=1.0)
>
> Set a tick on each integer multiple of a base within the view
>   interval.

We needa assign the plot to axes class and modify it like this:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np

sns.set()
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2,figsize=(10,4))

sns.barplot(x="total_bill",y="day",data=tips,ax=ax[0],ci=None)
ax[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(2.5))

sns.barplot(x="total_bill",y="day",data=tips,ax=ax[1],ci=None)
ax[1].xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Change `your_ticks` to an array that contains the numbers you want to appear on the x-axis.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.barplot(y='feature', x='nunique', data=df, orient = 'h')

ax.set_xticks(your_ticks)
```